# My nested IF in Postgresql doesn't work at all?

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures

My Nested if condition here doesn't work. I don't know why. I'm new in Postgresql. Can you help me out of this ? I don't know what to do. :'(

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pl_uploadhousehoold(mchholdnumber character varying, mcbrgycode character varying, mcstio character varying, mcstreet character varying, mnhousenumber character varying, mclat character varying, mclong character varying, mcrespondentname character varying, mddateinterview date, mdstattime character varying, mdendtime character varying, mcpurok character varying, mnuserid integer, mczone character varying, mccategory character varying, mfile_path_household character varying, mfile_path character varying, mfile_respondent character varying, mdyear date, mnuser integer,  mdaccomplished character varying, mdregistered character varying, mdvalidated character varying, mcsubcategory character varying, mcfacilityname character varying, mcposition character varying)
RETURNS SETOF tbl_household AS
$BODY$
DECLARE

 t_10 time without time zone; 
 t_11 time without time zone; 
 t_21 timestamp without time zone; 
 t_22 timestamp without time zone; 
 t_23 timestamp without time zone; 
 hh_id character varying;

 BEGIN  
    IF hh_id is NULL THEN           
      IF mdstattime !=''  THEN 
         t_10:=(select CAST (mdstattime as time without time zone) as dstattime); 
 INSERT INTO tbl_household(chholdnumber,cbrgycode,csitio,cstreet,nhousenumber,clat,clong,crespondentname,ddateinterview,dstattime,cpurok,nuserid,czone,ccategory,file_path_household, file_path, file_respondent,dyear,nuser, csubcategory, cfacilityname, cposition) 
                         values($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,t_10,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$24,$25,$26);   
      END IF;

      IF mdendtime !=''   THEN        
             t_11:=(select CAST (mdendtime as time without time zone) as dendtime);   
                  INSERT INTO tbl_household(chholdnumber,cbrgycode,csitio,cstreet,nhousenumber,clat,clong,crespondentname,ddateinterview,dendtime,cpurok,nuserid,czone,ccategory,file_path_household, file_path, file_respondent,dyear,nuser, csubcategory, cfacilityname, cposition) 
                       values($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,t_11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$24,$25,$26);   
      END IF;
      IF mdaccomplished !=''  THEN        
             t_21:=(select CAST (mdaccomplished as timestamp without time zone) as daccomplished); 


INSERT INTO tbl_household(chholdnumber,cbrgycode,csitio,cstreet,nhousenumber,clat,clong,crespondentname,ddateinterview,cpurok,nuserid,czone,ccategory,file_path_household, file_path, file_respondent,dyear,nuser,daccomplished, csubcategory, cfacilityname, cposition) 
                       values($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,t_21,$24,$25,$26);   
      END IF;
      IF mdregistered !=''  THEN        
             t_22:=(select CAST (mdregistered as timestamp without time zone) as dregistered);  
                  INSERT INTO tbl_household(chholdnumber,cbrgycode,csitio,cstreet,nhousenumber,clat,clong,crespondentname,ddateinterview,cpurok,nuserid,czone,ccategory,file_path_household, file_path, file_respondent,dyear,nuser,dregistered, csubcategory, cfacilityname, cposition) 
                       values($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,t_22,$24,$25,$26);   
      END IF;
      IF mdvalidated !=''  THEN        
              t_23:=(select CAST (mdvalidated as timestamp without time zone) as dvalidated);  
                  INSERT INTO tbl_household(chholdnumber,cbrgycode,csitio,cstreet,nhousenumber,clat,clong,crespondentname,ddateinterview,cpurok,nuserid,czone,ccategory,file_path_household, file_path, file_respondent,dyear,nuser,dvalidated, csubcategory, cfacilityname, cposition) 
                       values($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,t_23,$24,$25,$26);   
      END IF;
      IF mdaccomplished ='' and mdstattime='' and mdendtime='' and mdregistered ='' and mdvalidated =''  THEN        
                  INSERT INTO tbl_household(chholdnumber,cbrgycode,csitio,cstreet,nhousenumber,clat,clong,crespondentname,ddateinterview,cpurok,nuserid,czone,ccategory,file_path_household, file_path, file_respondent,dyear,nuser, csubcategory, cfacilityname, cposition) 
                       values($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$24,$25,$26);  
      END IF;

      IF mdaccomplished !='' and mdstattime!='' and mdendtime!='' and mdregistered !='' and mdvalidated !=''  THEN 
              t_22:=(select CAST (mdregistered as timestamp without time zone) as dregistered);  
              t_21:=(select CAST (mdaccomplished as timestamp without time zone) as daccomplished); 
              t_10:=(select CAST (mdstattime as time without time zone) as dstattime);    
              t_11:=(select CAST (mdendtime as time without time zone) as dendtime); 
              t_23:=(select CAST (mdvalidated as timestamp without time zone) as dvalidated);  
                   INSERT INTO tbl_household(chholdnumber,cbrgycode,csitio,cstreet,nhousenumber,clat,clong,crespondentname,ddateinterview,dstattime,dendtime,cpurok,nuserid,czone,ccategory,file_path_household, file_path, file_respondent,dyear,nuser,daccomplished,dregistered,dvalidated, csubcategory, cfacilityname, cposition) 
 values($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,t_10,t_11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,t_21,t_22,t_23,$24,$25,$26);   
      END IF;

      ELSE                      
     END IF;
```

I've tested my mdendtime with null values. But it the condition doesn't work.

Comment: "*doesn't work*" is not a valid Postgres error message. Can any of the variables you test (`mdendtime`, `mdstattime`) be `null`? And why are you comparing variables that are named "time" to string literals? What are the data types of those variables?

Comment: I've added the function part. It doesn't displays error but the condition part doesn't work at all :)

Comment: You need to explain *what* doesn't work - what is the example you are testing with, what is the behaviour you expect/want, and what is the actual behaviour? Have you tried [creating a simplified test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for both us and you to understand the problem better?

Comment: You function is way to complex, that's why things go wrong. Why did you write seven INSERT queries that do (almost) the same thing? Use one single INSERT and set the proper values (including default and nulls) for your columns.

Comment: sir @FrankHeikens. There is a tendency that not all the parameters has a value so i have to adjust the way it work ;)

Comment: In my database the timestamp without time zone and time without time zone data types will not accept null parameters so, i have to put a condition out there.

Comment: @jamesjuventud: If a parameter doesn't have a value, it becomes a NULL value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the last `ELSE` statement at the bottom of your function.

Furthermore, in your function you are using a very complicated way to convert a character string into a `time` or `timestamp` value, but none of that is necessary. Instead of doing:

```
IF mdendtime != '' THEN        
  t_11 := (select CAST (mdendtime as time without time zone) as dendtime);   
  INSERT INTO tbl_household(chholdnumber, dendtime, ...) 
    VALUES ($1, t_11, ...);   
END IF;
```

you can simply do:

```
  INSERT INTO tbl_household(chholdnumber, dendtime) 
    VALUES ($1, NULLIF(mdendtime, '')::time);
```

But like Frank Heikens said, your function is way too complex. You may end up doing 6 inserts of essentially the same data. Apparently you are doing household surveys in The Philippines and you want to store information on the location of the **household** and some **survey** data. Household and survey are two separate entities and in a proper database design all entities have their own table.

So start with putting all household data in a table `households`. When you have a new survey, check if the household data is already in the table. If so, retrieve the `hholdid`, otherwise insert the data in the `households` table `RETURNING hholdid`.

Now make a table `survey` which uses the `hholdid` from the `households` table as a foreign key. In the `survey` table you put columns for all relevant information, including `hholdid`, such as date of survey, start time, end time, etc. And then you can simply insert your survey information there, everything in a single row, without the need for a function.

Depending on what all the survey data means you might want to repeat this process of breaking up all of the data into entities. The respondent information looks like a good candidate: a single respondent will probably do multiple surveys, so make a respondent table with a `respid` primary key and store that value in your `survey` table.

This analysis of your "Universe-of-Discourse" is at the heart of good database modeling.

Comment: Sir @Patrick ? How did you know that i'm doing household survey in the Philippines ?

Comment: The Philippines are the only country in the world that I know of that use the term barangay (brgy in short) for neighbourhood.

Comment: yah ! :D haha! you're quite smart :)

Comment: Sir @Patrick ? my mdendtime has datatype 'time without time zone' in my database. I'll try if the database allowed the NULL value in that datatype. :)

Comment: NULL is allowed in every data type

Comment: It's a "BIG WOW" Sir. @Patrick. NULLIF statement solved my complex conditions. It's a big relief. Thank you man ! :D Cheeeers!